# How to Update SVG element attributes in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I use 4.4.4 version of Angular. In my `app.component.html` i have this code

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updatePosition()">Up</button>
    <svg id="svg">
        <image xlink:href="../assets/map.png" x="0" y="0" height="420px" width="420px"/>
    </svg>
```

I want to dynamically update `x` and `y` value when the button is pressed. I tried various methods to do that with no result.

for example i used property binding `[style.x.px]="variableX"` to define `x` position but despite pressing the button and updating variableX value nothing happed so it looks like i still have to update `x` position. Normally i would target that image with simple javascript and do `el.setAttribute('x', value)`  on it, but in angular it isn't that simple or just doesn't work for some reason.

Can anybody help? :)

Comment: property binding doesnt work because it only sets the initial value of it. it doesnt check it for changes. have you tried using two way binding?

Comment: I probably will, however i seek for a better solution to access this elements. I will have to do some more complitated operations on it.

Comment: `[style.<property>]` bindings set values that go into a `style` binding. `x.px` is not a valid css property, so it does not do anything. Have you tried binding to `[attr.x]` instead (e.g. `[attr.x]="variableX"`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a way to manipulate the x and y css properties of the image, I would use either:

[`NgStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) directive to dynamically get whatever value you want like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updatePosition()">Up</button>
<image xlink:href="../assets/map.png" height="420px" width="420px [ngStyle]="style" />

position = { 'x': '0', 'y': '0' };
//you can also add any other css properties to this like width and height
get style() {
  return this.position;
}
updatePosition() {
  this.position = { 'x': '10px', 'y': '10px' }; //however you update the values
}
```

Or use a local `ElementRef` and `@ViewChild` and manipulate the nativeElement directly in your ts like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updatePosition()">Up</button>
<image xlink:href="../assets/map.png" height="420px" width="420px" #image/>

@ViewChild('image') image: ElementRef;
updatePosition() {
  this.image.nativeElement.style.x = '10px'; //however you update the values
  this.image.nativeElement.style.y = '10px'; //however you update the values
}
```

Make sure you import `ViewChild` from "@angular/core" if you do this.

I haven't tested this in plunkr or anything, but I believe they should both work.

Comment: It solved my problem I think. I will use your method to improve my script. However, can you just explain how this "get style()" line works? Does it automatically update element proporties?

Comment: `get style()` is a get accessor. Its basically the same thing as any regular function, except a get accessor MUST return some value. Thats why, when you use it in the `ngStyle` directive in the html, you do `[ngStyle]="style"` instead of `[ngStyle]="style()"`. Because the get accessor MUST return a value, you call it without the parenthesis and its "value" is whatever it returns. and because the get accessor is essentially a function, putting it together with the `[ngStyle]` directive makes it "watch" the value that it returns.

Answer (score 4):

In order to bind to SVG element attributes In angular 2, you must prefix them with attr., e. g.:

```
<svg>  
    <circle [attr.r]="myRadius" cx="50" cy="50"></circle>  
</svg>
```

This is a great blog explaining issues with svg bindings in Angular 2: https://500tech.com/blog/all/svg-in-angular-2/

Comment: Of course, but it doesn't solve the problem. This is exactly the same way I described above.